# Maximize or Restore a Window doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a windows form which checks whether a process is minimized or not. If it is it should maximize it and bring the window to front. If the window is not maximized and is in the background the code is working properly and the window comes to the front. But when I check for isiconic i.e minimized it doesn't restore or maximize the window. My code is

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern
            bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern
            bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern
            bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);

        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
        private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            this.Visible = false;

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();            
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Connectivity.VaultPro"))
            {
                IntPtr hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
                // if iconic, we need to restore the window
                if (IsIconic(hWnd))
                {
                    //ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
                    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
                    //SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                }
                else
                {
                    ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);                    
                    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                }
                // bring it to the foreground
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

            }



            if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Temp"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\temp.png"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"C:\Temp\temp.png");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Temp");
            }
}
```

In the if condition I have tried it with ShowWindow and have also tried it with SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED and SW_RESTORE. Can someone tell me what may be the problem in the code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows does not maintain a *Main Window Handle* concept, as the property `Process.MainWindowHandle` implies. Make sure the handle you retrieve really is a **top level** window, or use the handle to navigate the hierarchy up to a top level window.

Comment: Use the Spy++ utility to double-check assumptions and verify that the window handle you got in fact matches the window that you are trying to mess with.  Never use ShowWindowAsync before calling SetForegroundWindow.

Comment: thanks guyz the problem was with the handle. I got it working through FindWindow.

Comment: You don't check for errors at all. A very common mistake for someone coming to Win32 from .net. Don't expect Win32 functions to throw exceptions when they fail. You must check for errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how to check for errors?

Comment: The documentation for each Win32 API function give details. You have to consider each function separately. The mechanisms for error handling are not uniform.